# How to set timezone showing on heroku pg:backups results?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When I run

```
heroku pg:backups
```

I get results like

```
=== Backups
ID    Backup Time                Status                               Size    Database
----  -------------------------  -----------------------------------  ------  --------
b015  2016-08-05 04:43:16 +0000  Completed 2016-08-05 04:43:19 +0000  132kB   DATABASE
a014  2016-08-04 21:03:23 +0000  Completed 2016-08-04 21:06:15 +0000  132kB   DATABASE
...
```

Can I set it to show timestamp on different timezone? says UTC+7. I tried set heroku config with

```
heroku config:add TZ="Asia/Bangkok"
```

and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku exclusively uses UTC for this. This is pretty much the standard for all web services as it ensures no times can be misinterpreted. You cannot change this output.